# Floor to ceiling bookshelf design: anything missing? okay to use MDF?

Tags: shelving, mdf, built-ins

Novice here. Building a book shelf along the full wall and floor-to-ceiling of my basement. Made up some plans, since I couldn't find any that really matched.  Wondering a few things.

1. Am I missing anything?
2. Do I need any additional support (will attach to wall)
3. I know MDF is looked down on, but am I "okay" to use it for the verticals like this? They seem SO Much easier with the pre-drilled holes...etc.
4. Do I need the header 2x4s?

Notes: Was thinking the bottom would be 2x6s (treated, since on concrete), and the top would be 2x4s (not sure if needed, but figured I want something for the crown molding to go on.

Any thoughts/suggestions/insults welcome. Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: MDF is looked down on? I think it's used far more often for bookcases than boards are; look at any flat pack stuff. It's a great material for this project, maybe ideal. If your pegs only go in half the board thickness you don't need to double up, unless that's a looks thing.

Comment: Do you plan to paint or protect the MDF in any way? In no time flat it could end up looking like this https://i.pinimg.com/236x/1a/9a/57/1a9a5738b27eac7a364db9e5ea03df96--woodworking-furniture-woodworking-tools.jpg. Particle board furniture is usually veneered from head to toe so that it's more difficult to cause damage. Also read https://www.bobvila.com/articles/mdf-vs-plywood/ for a good rundown of MDF versus plywood

Comment: Yes, @MonkeyZeus, I think the stuff I'm seeing has a veneer on the whole thing except probably the ends. It comes in 8ft lengths and has all the holes pre-drilled.

Comment: I cannot confirm nor deny your judgement unless you provide a picture :-)

Comment: Additionally [*Whatever you put in has to be considered a "feature" not a "what's that".*](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/216681/floor-to-ceiling-bookshelf-before-or-after-carpet#comment403916_216682)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's why I was concerned about using MDF. (it was mentioned "We tear down MDF crap and thin plywood")   I do want a feature.  Though I don't want a feature so bad that I'm willing to add 30 hours of labor or huge cost difference.

Comment: Is MDF the white boards in your mock-up? The light brown is regular wood and/or plywood?

Comment: What's the span of each shelf? Or just tell me the entire width of the bookshelf and I'll divide by 3.

Comment: You are the one who has to look at it everyday, what anyone else thinks about MDF does not matter.  If you like it, use it.

Comment: This may be better served over a Woodworking stack. https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the span of the whole thing is actually something like 14'.  I figure I'll be putting verticals every ~28".  Depth is 15.75".

Comment: @crip659 you're probably right! Didn't even know that existed. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask just one question per post. The suitability of MDF and the need for structural changes are not closely related.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, the white is the MDF.

Comment: Assuming that you're going to use 1/2" or 3/4 inch plywood for the shelves then you'll want to pick the one strong enough to not sag over time with the anticipated weight that you will put on the shelf. The vertical MDF boards are probably fine but if a dowel ever rips out (or downward) due to overloading then it will likely damage the MDF in a similar fashion to the image I posted earlier.

Comment: You said you are using treated wood because this will be on concrete. Is dampness a problem in this room? Like a basement that leaks? If there are moisture issues I would not use mdf. If a ranch type home on a slab you could always put a layer of plastic down for additional moisture protection. To tell if your slab is damp tape a piece of plastic to the floor for 24 hours. When you pull it up water drops on the plastic it really wet, even a fairly dry floor the plastic may be dry but the concrete may look darker. And if no change in color bone dry (or under water lol)

Comment: @EdBeal It is on concrete slab in basement, but I've done the moisture tests and everything came up dry / good. I don't believe I have a moisture problem, but as far as I understood, you're supposed to use treated lumber whenever you have wood up against concrete. At least that's what I did for the base of all the walls. Maybe overkill, but not overly expensive, so...

Comment: With test results coming up dry I would not worry much about moisture. When I build cabinets I use plywood but I still do a lot of “old school” things that have never let me down.

Comment: @Dave Just use pressure treated when touching the floor and call it a day. There's no reason to build this and then lose sleep thinking about "what if it rots?" A few unexpected rainstorms and the concrete will gladly wick moisture into the wood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Ended up building the base and two verticals with treated 2x4s, and regular 2x4s for cross-support around the fireplace.  Then sandwiched-in the verticals with MDF.

As you can see, I also used big L-brackets to support the long horizontals.  Likely a bit overboard there, but I think they'll look okay once it's filled. Was hoping for a long, open spans aesthetic instead of putting extra verticals in.

The MDF looks nice for now. It does have little dings and nicks. Went with a rustic looking wood pattern, so it doesn't seem to affect the overall look. So far. We'll see how well it holds up over the years.  It was certainly nice to work with, and saved a lot of painting. I think I'd use it again if I were to make another.

I haven't put the baseboard across the bottom yet. Haven't decided if I'm going to use the white baseboard that will be in the room, or more of this wood-looking mdf 3.5" pieces like the verticals.

[image: bookshelf]